# Trouble proving outer regularity of measure in proof of the multiplication version of the spectral theorem in Dunford & Schwartz

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

In Dunford & Schwartz Linear Operators Part II X.5.4, they start with a bounded normal operator
$T$ on a (not necessarily separable) Hilbert space $\mathfrak{H}$. In the previous theorem,
they proved that there is a maximal collection
of mutually orthogonal closed subspaces $\{\mathfrak{H}_\alpha:\alpha\in M\}$ of $\mathfrak{H}$,
each of which is reducing for $T$, with the additional property that each $\mathfrak{H}_\alpha$ has an element $\bar{x}_\alpha$ such that the set
\begin{equation*}
  \{p(T_\alpha,T_\alpha^*)\bar{x}_\alpha: p(T_\alpha,T_\alpha^*)
  \text{ is a polynomial in $T_\alpha$ and $T_\alpha^*$}\}
\end{equation*}
is dense in $\mathfrak{H}_\alpha$, where $T_\alpha$ is the restriction of $T$ to
$\mathfrak{H}_\alpha$. They also show that for each $\alpha\in M$,
there is a finite positive regular Borel measure $\mu_\alpha$ on the Borel subsets of
$\mathbb{C}$, which vanishes on $\sigma(T_\alpha)^c\supseteq\sigma(T)^c$,
and a Hilbert space isomorphism $U$ of
$\mathfrak{H}$ onto $\sum_{\alpha\in M} L^2(\mu_\alpha)$ such that for every Borel measurable function,
$f$, defined and bounded on $\sigma(T)$, and every $x\in\mathfrak{H}$, and every $\alpha\in M$,
$$(U(f(T)x))_\alpha(\lambda)=f(\lambda)(Ux)_\alpha(\lambda),$$
for $\mu_\alpha$-almost all $\lambda$. ($\sum_{\alpha\in M} L^2(\mu_\alpha)$ is the
Hilbert space sum of the $L^2(\mu_a)$ Hilbert spaces.)

In the present theorem, they will define a set $S$, a $\sigma$-algebra, $\Sigma$, on $S$ and
a regular positive measure $\mu$ on $\Sigma$. There are other parts to the theorem,
but where I am having trouble is in the proof of the outer regularity of $\mu$ (inner regularity
does not seem to pose any problems). So, what follows are the definitions of $S$, $\Sigma$, and
$\mu$.

For each $\alpha\in M$, let $S_\alpha=\sigma(T_\alpha)$. Let
$$S=\{(s_\alpha,\alpha):s_\alpha\in S_\alpha,\,\alpha\in M\}.$$
So $S$ is the disjoint union of all of the $S_\alpha$, where they've been "tagged" by $\alpha$ to keep them separate. If $e\subseteq S$, let
$$e_\alpha=\{s_\alpha: (s_\alpha,\alpha)\in e\}.$$
I call this a "slice" of $e$. Note that the above notation makes sense, even if $S$ is substituted
for $e$. Let
$$\Sigma=\{e\subseteq S: e_\alpha\in\mathscr{B}_\alpha\text{ for each $\alpha\in M$}\},$$
where $\mathscr{B}_\alpha$ are the Borel subsets of $S_\alpha$ (which is the same as the
Borel subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ which are contained in $S_\alpha$). Let
$$\mu(e)=\sum_{\alpha\in M}\mu_\alpha(e_\alpha)\qquad(e\in\Sigma),$$
if the sum converges, and $\infty$ otherwise. To talk about regularity, we need a topology for $S$.
We will define a metric. Let
\begin{equation*}
  d((s_\alpha,\alpha),(s_\beta,\beta))=
  \begin{cases}
    \lvert s_\alpha-s_\beta\rvert&\text{if $\alpha=\beta$},\\
    \lvert\lvert T\rvert\rvert&\text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

I have no trouble showing that $d$ is a metric on $S$, that for $r\leq\lvert\lvert T\rvert\rvert$,
\begin{equation*}
  B_S((s_\alpha,\alpha),r)=\{(s_\beta,\beta)\in S: d((s_\alpha,\alpha),(s_\beta,\beta))<r\}
  =(B(s,r) \cap S_\alpha)\times\{\alpha\},
\end{equation*}
that $e\subseteq S$ is open if and only if $e_\alpha$ is relatively open in $S_\alpha$ for each
$\alpha\in M$, and that $K\subseteq S$ is compact if and only if $K_\alpha$ is compact for each
$\alpha\in M$, and nonempty for at most a finite number of $\alpha\in M$. I can show that
$\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra in $S$ (and, in fact contains the Borel subsets of $S$), and that
$\mu$ is a positive measure on $\Sigma$, which is inner regular. I can't seem to prove that $\mu$
is outer regular. Here is the proof in the text: "It is readily seen that $(S,\Sigma,\mu)$ is a
regular measure space."

So what's the hangup? Well, let $e\in\Sigma$. If $\mu(e)=\infty$, there is no problem since
all open $V$ containing $e$ will have $\mu(V)=\infty$ as well. So suppose
$\mu(e)=\sum_{\alpha\in M}\mu_\alpha(e_\alpha)<\infty$. Then $\mu_\alpha(e_\alpha)>0$ for
at most a countably infinite number of $\alpha$, say $\alpha\in\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots\}$.
For all the rest of the $\alpha\in M$, we have $\mu_\alpha(e_\alpha)=0$. Now given $\epsilon>0$
we have to find an open set $V$ in $S$ which contains $e$ and which has
$\mu(V)=\sum_{\alpha\in M}\mu_\alpha(V_\alpha)<\mu(e)+\epsilon$. My problem is with all those
$\alpha\in M-\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots\}$. For each one, we must have $e_\alpha\subseteq V_\alpha$,
and $V_\alpha$ needs to be relatively open in $S_\alpha$. Unless I can guarantee that
$\mu_\alpha(V_\alpha)=0$ for all but countably many of those $\alpha$, I'm going to wind up
with $\sum_{\alpha\in M}\mu_\alpha(V_\alpha)$ not converging (and therefore being infinite).
Right now, I don't see how to accomplish this. The only idea that came to mind was to try to show
that there must be an open set $U$ in $S$ containing $e$ such that $\mu(U)<\infty$, but I couldn't
even do that. Any ideas on how to proceed would be appreciated.