# Looking for counterexample to outer regularity of the measure in Dunford & Schwartz X.5.4.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

I recently posted this question [Trouble proving outer regularity of measure in proof of the multiplication version of the spectral theorem in Dunford & Schwartz](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3754005/527829) where I was not able
to confirm the outer regularity of the measure, $\mu$, constructed in the proof of the theorem.
I am now beginning to wonder if, in fact, it is not necessarily true that $\mu$ is regular. So I'd
like to explore creating a counterexample. Obviously $\mathfrak{H}$ would have to be non-separable.
But my
repertoire of bounded normal operators on non-separable Hilbert spaces along with knowledge of their
spectra and spectral decompositions is extremely limited. What I'm hoping to get to is a
maximal collection of mutually orthogonal closed reducing subspaces,
$\{\mathfrak{H}_\alpha:\alpha\in M\}$ of $\mathfrak{H}$, for a bounded normal operator
$T$, where $M$ is uncountable, and such that $\sigma(T_\alpha)$ ($T_\alpha$ is the restriction
of $T$ to $\mathfrak{H}_\alpha$) and the resolution of the identity
for $T$ are easy to calculate/describe. My hope is
then for an uncountable number of $\alpha\in M$, that I can find a Borel subset, $A$, of
$\sigma(T_\alpha)$, which is not relatively open in $\sigma(T_\alpha)$, so that any containing relatively open subset of $\sigma(T_\alpha)$ has nonzero
measure with respect to the finite regular measure $\mu_\alpha$ derived from the the resolution
of the identity for $T$, as in the theorem.

So, what are some good candidates for

1. the non-separable Hilbert space $\mathfrak{H}$
2. the bounded normal operator $T$ on $\mathfrak{H}$?

An additional question would be, even if there is a counterexample, is the theorem in Dunford & Schwartz still true? That
is does there exist a regular $\mu$, but the measure created in the proof isn't necessarily it? And the final question would be, should I care if $\mu$ is not regular? Is it important for applications?

Comment: You write that you want an operator $T$ and a collection $M_\alpha$ of reducing subspaces as well as a Borel subset $A$ of $\Bbb C$ (right? you write $\sigma(T_\alpha)$ but that means you choose for each $\alpha$ a different set) so that $\mu_\alpha(A)$ is a non-zero projection for uncountably many $\alpha$. Are you sure this is what you are looking for? Because if you take $A=\Bbb C$ then this is a given. Or if you take $T=\Bbb 1$ and $A=\{1\}$.

Comment: @s.harp I wrote that I want to find, for each of an uncountable number of α, a Borel subset, A, of σ(Tα) (which means that A=C is not a candidate). However, your other point is well-taken. I want to find a subset, A, of σ(Tα) which is not relatively open in σ(Tα) such that μα(U)>0 for any relatively open U⊃A. I will edit the question to reflect this. Thanks.